# Best practice for display and hiding of loading gifs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, loading

I have a page in which I click a button to load the contents of another page into a div.
I have a loading gif which I want to display when I click the button and and of course which I would like to disappear when the content of the other page has fully loaded into the div "maincontent". Below is my current code - is this the best practice to achieve this effect - somehow I think there must be a better way to do it?

**index.php:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#loading').hide();

        $(document).on('click', '.menu1', function(){
          $('#loading').show();
          $('.maincontent').load("1.php");
        });

      });
    </script>

    <style>
      #loading {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        position: fixed;
        display: block;
        opacity: 0.7;
        background-color: #fff;
        z-index: 99;
        text-align: center;
      }

      #loading-image {
        position: absolute;
        top: 25%;
        left: 50%;
        z-index: 100;
      }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <button class="menu1">Click</button>
    <div class="maincontent">
      <div id="loading">
        <img id="loading-image" src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." />
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.ajaxStart` and `.ajaxStop`  events to show and hide loader respectively. Please check below snippet.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#loading').hide().ajaxStart( function() {
        $(this).show();  // show Loading Div
    } ).ajaxStop ( function(){
        $(this).hide(); // hide loading div
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.menu1', function(){
      $('.maincontent').load("1.php");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul however I have more than one button and when clicking the other button after the 1st has been clicked the loading div is not displayed it is as if the ajax request is not being acknowledged